# Change ContentTemplate of Contentpresenter through Templatebinding

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, contentpresenter, templatebinding

Is it possible to do something like this (See code below)? I tried different ways but none of them worked. Is it a limitation to TemplateBinding? I don't want to set the ContentTemplates via Staticressources (this works) because the Control should change Templates during runtime. How can I achieve this?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:mycontrol}">
<Grid x:Name="root" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" >
    <ContentPresenter Opacity="0" x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding MinimizedContentTemplate}">
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ControlState" Value="Maximized">
        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{TemplateBinding MaximizedContentTemplate}"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:mycontrol}">
    <Setter Property="ControlState" Value="Minimized" />
    <Setter Property="MaximizedContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultMaxContentTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="MinimizedContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultMinContentTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource myControlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TemplateBinding` does not seem to work correctly with custom properties on custom controls. You can try to use a `RelativeSource Binding` to the `TemplatedParent` property instead:

```
<ContentPresenter Opacity="0" x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{Binding 
    MinimizedContentTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

You can find out more from the [`TemplatedParent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: The thing is I want to set the ContentTemplate inside of the triggers. But I think i might have found a solution that works. Will update here soon

Comment: Oh ok I'm surprised. Your Solution works aswell inside the triggers. Thanks =)

Comment: Why is that surprising? A valid `Binding.Path` is a valid `Binding.Path` regardless of where it is defined.